# Google PageSpeed Insights show unidentified scripts in results

Tags: pagespeed

I am testing my home page (http://stayuncle.com/home) speed at Google PageSpeed Insights. In result, I am getting few unidentified java script. I have no idea how they get into the results.

[image]

Can someone help me to understand how they get into result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up a network tab and view the results when the page loads you will see that those scripts load with the page. This script isn't coming from Google PageSpeed, but rather from your own site. It seems to be coming from a metrics script and is pushing mixpanel results.

This is the URL inside the script.

http://popcornmetrics.com/legal

Unfortunately, I am not able to see what initiated the script. You might want to go through each of your JavaScript files and check if it isn't loaded from there!

Comment: Yes, through debugging I come to know these are script called through my tracking script.

Comment: Hi, I'm coFounder of PopcornMetrics. We have a new library which is minified and zipped, so the Google PageSpeed will show a better performance now. They have [PopcornMetrics](http://www.PopcornMetrics.com) installed in their website, that's why the script is loading.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is [PopcornMetrics](http://www.popcornmetrics.com) script and library installed in your website (http://stayuncle.com/home). Our new library has a minified and gzipped version which will show better results in Google PageSpeed.